# How do you handle complex namespaces in XQuery/BaseX?

Tags: xml, xquery, basex, reqif

I have a relatively complex XML file following the ReqIF standard that I wish to manipulate using BaseX. When I strip out all of the `xlmns` attributes in the `REQ-IF` node, then I can perform XQueries and traverse the file (e.g., `//REQ-IF/THE-HEADER`) in the XQuery bar, and see the results as expected.

However when I include the `xlmns` attributes, none of the queries work. Even worse, when I select a node in the Map View to copy the path and paste it into the XQuery bar, no results are returned either.

So, how does one express an XQuery (using presumably the namespace information) to get to the innards of this XML file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<REQ-IF xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/ReqIF/20110401/reqif.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.omg.org/spec/ReqIF/20110401/reqif.xsd reqif.xsd" xmlns:reqif="http://www.omg.org/spec/ReqIF/20110401/reqif.xsd" xmlns:reqif-xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:rm-reqif="http://www.ibm.com/rm/reqif" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <THE-HEADER>
    </THE-HEADER>
    <CORE-CONTENT>
        <REQ-IF-CONTENT>
            <DATATYPES>             
            </DATATYPES>
            <SPEC-TYPES>
            </SPEC-TYPES>
            <SPEC-OBJECTS>
            </SPEC-OBJECTS>
            <SPEC-RELATIONS>
            </SPEC-RELATIONS>
            <SPECIFICATIONS>
            </SPECIFICATIONS>
            <SPEC-RELATION-GROUPS>
            </SPEC-RELATION-GROUPS>
        </REQ-IF-CONTENT>
    </CORE-CONTENT>
</REQ-IF>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, look into your favourite XQuery tutorial or in the spec, it shows you can declare a default element namespace https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-default-namespace

```
declare default element namespace "http://www.omg.org/spec/ReqIF/20110401/reqif.xsd";

/REQ-IF/CORE-CONTENT/REQ-IF-CONTENT/DATATYPES
```

(example https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPgCcoC)

or another namespace https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-namespace-declaration

```
declare  namespace reqif = "http://www.omg.org/spec/ReqIF/20110401/reqif.xsd";

/reqif:REQ-IF/reqif:CORE-CONTENT/reqif:REQ-IF-CONTENT/reqif:DATATYPES
```

(online at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPgCcoC/1)

In addition there wild card namespace expressions like `/*:REQ-IF` and enhanced QNames like (`/Q{http://www.omg.org/spec/ReqIF/20110401/reqif.xsd}REQ-IF`)

Comment: Thanks for that. I had tried something similar to your first suggestion, but couldn't quite get it to work, but that worked right off the bat.